# TypeScript via tsc command: Output to single file without concatenation

Tags: javascript, typescript, bundle, tsc, transpiler

Is there a way of compiling single .ts file to different directory?

The only way from the manual command of compilation to different directory is via `--out` command, but it also does concatenation of dependent files, which I don't want:

```
--out FILE|DIRECTORY        Concatenate and emit output to single file | Redirect output structure to the directory
```

Is there a way of redirecting the output WITHOUT concatenation of input files?

Comment: Just FYI, using `--outFile` limits your module generation choices to **only "AMD" and "System"** per the doc: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately it's impossible to compile multiple `*.ts` files into one `*.js` without concatenation. Because it's impossible on API level of typescript compile options.

See `--out` option:

> DEPRECATED. Use --outFile instead.

**Documentation of `--outFile` option:**

> Concatenate and emit output to single file. The order of concatenation is determined by the list of files passed to the compiler on the command line along with triple-slash references and imports. See output file order documentation for more details.

All [typescript compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Answer (score 7):

It does one or the other.  If there's no `.js` extension on that file name it should assume a directory.

`tsc -out output.js filea.ts fileb.ts...`  <- output to single file output.js

`tsc -out output filea.ts fileb.ts...` <- output individual files to dir output

`tsc -out output/output.js filea.ts fileb.ts...`  <- output to single file in another directory

Comment: I think it's not a correct answer on a question. Question was Output to single file **without concatenation**. But here just list of --out commands

Comment: How do you get tsc to produce a flat build? By flat I mean one that doesn't have a dependancy on systemjs or requirejs? I'm trying to produce a lean build for npm.

Comment: i was looking to compiled to a different directory and this answer solved my problem tsc -out output filea.ts